# I'm getting a weird type of error while running

Tags: string, loops, c++11

Write a program that will take a string
S
as input and will remove vowels a, e, i, o, u (in lower or upper case) from the string. If two or more than two vowels occur together, then the program shall ignore all of those vowels.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define rep(a, b, c) for (int a = b; a < c; a++)
#define vi vector<int>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool yo;
    yo = false;
    int he;
    string s = "Heel";
    int i = 0;
    // cin >> s;
    while (i < s.length())
    {

        if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u' || s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'U')
        {

            if (s[i + 1] == 'a' || s[i + 1] == 'e' || s[i + 1] == 'i' || s[i + 1] == 'o' || s[i + 1] == 'u' || s[i + 1] == 'A' || s[i + 1] == 'E' || s[i + 1] == 'I' || s[i + 1] == 'O' || s[i + 1] == 'U')
            {
                while (s[he + 1] != 'a' || s[he + 1] != 'e' || s[he + 1] != 'i' || s[he + 1] != 'o' || s[he + 1] != 'u' || s[he + 1] != 'A' || s[he + 1] != 'E' || s[he + 1] != 'I' || s[he + 1] != 'O' || s[he + 1] != 'U' || he < s.length())
                {
                    he++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), s[i]), s.end());
            }
            i = i + he;
            he = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: `s[he + 1]` accesses uninitialized variable `he`, whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an access memory violation because s[he + 1] reaches another memory sector that hasn't been reserved to `s`.

You are creating a kind of infinity loop that runs while any vowel appears and the most important validation is at the end of conditions when it MUST be at the being to validate that there is no chance to touch an invalid sector of memory.

Your code:

```cpp
while (s[he + 1] != 'a' || s[he + 1] != 'e' || s[he + 1] != 'i' || s[he + 1] != 'o' || s[he + 1] != 'u' || s[he + 1] != 'A' || s[he + 1] != 'E' || s[he + 1] != 'I' || s[he + 1] != 'O' || s[he + 1] != 'U' || he < s.length())
```

My suggestion:

```cpp
he = 0;
bound = s.length() - 1;
while (he < bound && (s[he + 1] != 'a' || ... || s[he + 1] != 'U'))
{
  //..
  he++;
}
```

If `he < s.length()` the remainder condition wont be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input().lower()
vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}  # Use a set for faster membership check
lst = []

if len(s) == 0:
    print("")

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s.count(s[i]) == 1 and s[i] in vowels:
        continue
    else:
        lst.append(s[i])

print("".join(lst))



    <pre>
    s = input().lower()
    vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'} 
    lst = []

    if len(s) == 0:
        print("")

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s.count(s[i]) == 1 and s[i] in vowels:
            continue
        else:
            lst.append(s[i])

    print("".join(lst))

    </pre>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).